# List of Persistent Favourites

Tags: javascript, html, persistence, local-storage

I need to keep track of a list of 25 favourites which are added from a list of ~100 entries. These favourites would be in a list of say

- "favourite 1"
- "favourite 2"
- "favourite 3"
  .... so on

and I need them to be stored persistently. I also would require them to be able to be deleted and replaced with another favourite string value. I have looked at [How do I store an array in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage) but that doesn't work for me because when I declare `var names=[];` on the javascript file, every time my favourites function runs it redeclares the array and clears everything.

I have tried doing something like:

```
function addToFav(string)
{
    if (localStorage.fav1)  // if fav1 was created before
    {
        alert("local storage fav1 present, don't make variables");
    }
    else
    {
        alert('fav variables never made, make them now');
        var i=1;
        for (i=1; i<=25; i++)
        {
            var favNumber = "fav" + i;
            localStorage.favNumber = "x";
        }
        alert(localStorage.fav1);                   // outputs "undefined"
    }
}
```

it was my intention to make localStorage variables of `fav1`,`fav2`,`fav3`...`fav25` and then manage them individually. But this doesn't work since calling `localStorage.favNumber = "x";` makes the **local storage variable** `favNumber`equal to `"x"` and not `fav+i`.

I'm out of ideas at the moment; I have looked at http://playground.html5rocks.com/#async_transactions to try using a HTML5 database but I'm very new to web development and it seems a bit too much for what I'm trying to do. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Any information would be helpful.

Comment: u shld use localStorage["fav"+i] = "x" ;

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I use these to store info in Local Storage with cookie backup...

```
function setLocalStorage(c_name, value) {
    var exdays = 30;
    // if localStorage is present, use that
    if (('localStorage' in window) && window.localStorage !== null) {
        localStorage[c_name] = value;
    } else {
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" +     exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }
}

function getLocalStorage(c_name) {
    // if localStorage is present, use that
    if (('localStorage' in window) && window.localStorage !== null) {
        return localStorage[c_name];
    } else {
        var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
            x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (x == c_name) {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```