# What can be stored in DOM Storage?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage, session-storage

Can any object be stored in a [DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)?

When I do the following:

```
// where val is a string and response is an array of objects.
sessionStorage.results= { val: response };
```

When I inspect value of `sessionStorage.results` I get `"[object Object]"`

Can I store objects like that? Or does Storage only stores strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only store strings in any type of [(DOM-)storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage). To store data objects (plain: no circular references, no special constructors) you can convert them to JSON and back from a string to restore them. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10109307/1048572) ([improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3146971/1048572)).

Comment: Am I blind? I can't find a question on SO to link, concerning that JSON-text transformation. There must be one!

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: Nah, I meant questions (like this) where users try to store objects in `localStorage` and get explanations of `JSON.stringify` and `.parse` in that context.

Comment: yeah, really blind: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2010892/1048572 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3357553/1048572