# Access to device memory when using PhoneGapBuild

Tags: javascript, cookies, cordova, filesystems

I need to save some simple seed data to generate some user-saved info when my PhoneGap app is launched, so all I need is a simple array or string to be saved to the device. I am lazy and I am using PhoneGapBuild rather than setting up PhoneGap locally.

The problem with this approach is that I can't modify the source files that would otherwise grant access to cookies functionality and filesystem stuff.

I'm hoping there is a simple way to store a bit of data (I have looked at cookies, filesystem access and a possible database plugin) that I have overlooked, and that will compile with PGB.

And does filesystem access even natively work with PGB? I haven't been able to get it going but I haven't *really* tried hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had overlooked something. The localStorage object. It stores data locally and can be accessed only by the browser that saved it. It is a html5 feature and luckily it works on Apache Cordova - the PhoneGap browser/wrapper. You use them as such:

```
localStorage.myData = 'string';
// or
localStorage['myData'] = 'string';
// or
localStorage.setItem('myData', 'string');
```

and to return

```
localStorage.myData;
// or
localStorage['myData'];
//or
localStorage.getItem('myData');
```

WAY easier to use than file API, and if you want to store arrays, use

```
localStorage.myArray = JSON.stringify(array);
```

and to return

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.myArray);
```

Many thanks to [How do I store an array in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage)