# Storing array in localStorage with JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, html

I have refereed this question and worked for me:   [so q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

Now Issue is that I have used JSON.stringify & JSON.parse to store array in localStorage. But when I run the code again and try to use JSON.parse on localStorage nothing get retrived. I dont know whats going wrong.

here is code:

```
    function BankProDisplay() {
        var myString = JSON.parse(localStorage['bankpro']);
        var mySplitResult = myString.split(",");
        for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('bankpro').innerHTML = document.getElementById('bankpro').innerHTML + mySplitResult[i] + "<br/>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would do a few tests in the Javascript console while running this code in a browser to check what value is stored at localStorage['bankpro'] to ensure that it is the stringified JSON you are expecting.  If you are getting that value out correctly see what happens when you try to JSON.parse(...) that result.

Comment: You don't need to serialize your data to store it in localStorage - you can actually just shove an array into localStorage quite happily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myString = JSON.parse(localStorage['bankpro']);
```

`JSON.parse` returns a javascript object, not a string, which would not have a `split` method.

Comment: Yup got it. In my code i just converted object to string. And worked fine. myString.toString().split(",");

Comment: you don't need the `toString()` - localStorage accessors will always give you a string. glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If you store an Array in LocalStorage using JSON.stringify, then you get it back using  JSON.parse, return value is Array, not string. So when you are using function mySplitResult for myString (which is actually Array, thanks to JSON.parse), then it leads to an Error. So remove function mySplitResult and it should work fine.