# HTML5 localStorage getting key from value

Tags: javascript, html

localStorage.getItem will retrive value.

and setItem will set value.

But If I want to know which key was associated with this particular value? Then how to get Key of that.?

[so question I have reffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

Comment: The code you posted is completely useless, what is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: i know the value , now i want to know which key was associated with it.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

visit  [Html5 Storage Doc](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)  to get more details. Use the following syntax to set and get the values in localstorage/sessionstorage
for storing values for a session

```
sessionStorage.getItem('key')
sessionStorage.setItem('key','value')
```

or store values permanently using

```
localStorage.getItem('key')
localStorage.setItem('key','value')
```

and u said u want to know the value but you want key then you can use the function

```
  localStorage.key(i);
```

or also you can loop through the available keys and get the desired key by cross checking the value

```
for(var i=0, len=localStorage.length; i<len; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    if(value.equals(desired_value))
    console.log(key + " => " + value);
}
```

Comment: code updated!! plz check nw!!

Comment: You have key and value the wrong way around in `localStorage.setItem('value', 'key')`. the key is the first argument, the value is the second argument.