# How can I remove a localStorage key-pair value by searching for the value instead of the key?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Let's say my localStorage looks something like this.

> item1: 123,
>   item2: 124,
>   token: 5487354787

Is there any way I can do something like `localStorage.removeItem('123')` instead of having to do `localStorage.removeItem("item1")`?

Comment: You can loop through localStorage and delete: [HTML5 localStorage getting key from value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949723) (That question is closed and Danziger's answer is much better)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate over all entries in `localStorage` using [`Object.entries()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=mdn+object.entries&oq=mdn+object.entries&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.4447j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
function removeLocalStorageValue(targetValue) {
  Object.entries(localStorage).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value === targetValue) localStorage.removeItem(key);
  });
}
```

Alternatively, the same can be done with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
function removeLocalStorageValue(targetValue) {
  Object.keys(localStorage).forEach((key) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem(key) === targetValue) localStorage.removeItem(key);
  });
}
```