# how to store value on click event

Tags: jquery, html

```
var btnlist="";
$("#divPopup").on("click", "li", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    // get currect id an replace with right
    var newId = $this.attr('Id').replace("Left", "Right")
    // check if the image is not for True
    if ($('#' + newId).find('img').attr('class') != 'checkImage') {
        $this.toggleClass("selected");
        if ($this.attr('class') == "selected") {
            btnlist.
            $('#' + newId).show(); // <== i want to store Newid each time when.show() method ex
        }
        else {
            var newId = $this.attr('Id').replace("Left", "Right")
            $('#' + newId).hide();
        }
    }
});
```

i want to store btnlist.`$('#' + newId).show();` <== i want to store **Newid** each time when.show() method execute, How can i store it.?

for example, there is  10 li element all are hidden ! , now let's see i click on 5 li element, and made them as show!

how can i create list of visiable items ? something like this var visiable = ([li1, li2, li3,li4,li5]); which line of code i need to put more to achieve something like this

Comment: Instead of `$this.attr('class') == "selected"`, i would use either `$this.is('.selected')` or `$this.hasClass('selected')`

Comment: You may want to add `HTML5` and `javascript` tags to your question.

Comment: Perhaps you try to explain WHAT you want to achieve when you "store" something in btnlist - there might be a better way to achieve your desired result than the one you imagined

Comment: my question has been updated

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage` or `localStorage` are key/value pairs, all you have to do is:

```
sessionStorage.newId = newId;
```

You may want to check if browser is supporting it with:

```
if(typeofsessionStorage)!=="undefined")
{
  // storage supported
}
```

**Update**

`sessionStorage` and `localStorage` don't support arrays, but you can store your data as json strings:

```
sessionStorage.newIds = JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]);
var ids = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.newIds);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand, do you want to store an array inside `sessionStorage`?

Comment: Yes,right i want all visible li elements, may be array is option

Comment: Check my edited answer, unfortunetly it seems that it makes it a dupicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage), am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Amplifyjs Store Plugin](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/).

*From documentation :*

> amplify.store is a wrapper for various persistent client-side storage systems. amplify.store supports IE 5+, Firefox 2+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Opera 10.5+, iPhone 2+, Android 2+ and provides a consistent API to handle storage cross-browser.

Sample Usage :

```
amplify.store(key, value)       // => store the value on the given key

var value = amplify.store(key); // => extract the value on the given key
```

**EDIT**

For storing values in HTML5 session storage you should check out this link :

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/

**EDIT-2**

I have created a fiddle in which you can see a code for accessing all li items and how to save clicked items.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DqnqY/2/)

Comment: Thanks For reply :) , but i am not looking for storage , i want all visiable items and store them in html 5 session storage

Comment: But i  am really not looking for the way the storing part, i need list of IDs when i click !, that's all sir :(

Comment: @NestorC can you please EDIT your question and specifically define what you actually want

Comment: @NestorC please check the updated answer `(EDIT-2)`, i created a fiddle according to what i understood from you edit, hope this time it helps