# HTML5 show localStorage element with specific content

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        for (i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++) 
        {
            var key = localStorage.key(i);
            if(key == "5") 
            {
                var value = localStorage.getItem(key); 
                document.write(value + "<br />");
            }
        }
</script>
```

I have tried to print all the element with a specific content - for a demo it could
be 5, but I couldn't get it.

Any help?

Comment: *sidenote:* in HTML5, `type` attribute in `<script>` tag is optional

Comment: From where you Created LocalStorage, when Loading Page Itself there will not be any LocalStorage,

Comment: Are you sure that you have the key in local storage. You should console.log(localStorage), or check resourses tab in developer tools if you are using chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Given that LocalStorage (as all key-based storage systems) doesn't allow for multiple elements having the same key, there are some solutions:

1. Store an *array* inside a single key and iterate over that array. Remember LocalStorage only supports strings, so you have to stringify/parse when writing/reading to LocalStorage:

   ```
   var elements = [], 
       elements[0] = {name: "Alpha"}, 
       elements[1] = {name: "Beta"}, 
       elements[2] = {name: "Gamma"};

   // Save
   localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(elements);
   // Read
   var elements = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
   ```
2. Use "dot notation" paths as keys and implement some sort of path parsing:

   ```
   var elements = [], 
       elements[0] = {name: "Alpha"}, 
       elements[1] = {name: "Beta"}, 
       elements[2] = {name: "Gamma"}, 
       elementsKey = 5;

   // Save
   for(var e = 0; e < elements.length; e ++) {
       // Elements get stored in "5.0", "5.1", "5.2", …
       var key = elementsKey + "." + e;
       localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(elements[e]);
   }

   // Read
   var baseKey = 5; // This is the "root" key to search for children
   for (var e = 0; e < localStorage.length; e++) {
       var key = localStorage.key(e);
       var subKey = key.split(".").pop(); // this is the "sub" key for this children element
       if(key.indexOf(baseKey) >= 0) {
           var element = localStorage.getItem(key);
       }
   }
   ```

Now i don't know what you are really storing inside those keys, but this should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Local Storage Varibale Ebfore to Iterate, Your Iteration code will fire when Page Load happends

```
window.localStorage.setItem("1", "AKSAHY");
window.localStorage.setItem("2", "John");
window.localStorage.setItem("3", "Manu");
window.localStorage.setItem("4", "Albert");
window.localStorage.setItem("5", "Mathew");


 for (i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++) 
        {
            var key = localStorage.key(i);
            if(key == "5") 
            {
                var value = localStorage.getItem(key); 
                alert(value + "<br />");
            }
        }
```

Check DEMO :- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/452LE/)

Comment: Thanks! But I need to display *all* of the elements that have the key "5" .. with the code you have sent I can display only one key.

Comment: LocalStorage should have Uniques keys, so then How do you store two different values with same key

Comment: If you want to display all just remove the If Condition just alert it

Comment: @AkshayJoy is correct. You cannot have multiple values with same key. You can, instead, have a single key hold an _array_ of objects.

Comment: @sixFingers then how can I code it? I need to display all the elments with a specific content.

Comment: @Oe Amranov -check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage