# How can I use a <select> in AngularJS to select from an array and then store that value in localStorage?

Tags: angularjs

I created the following:

```
    $scope.option.questionOrderBy = [
    { label: 'PId', key: ['problemId', 'QuestionId'] },
    { label: 'QId', key: 'questionId' },
    { label: 'Modified By', key: 'modifiedBy' },
    { label: 'Modified Date', key: 'modified' },
    { label: 'Status', key: 'questionStatusId' },
    { label: 'Title', key: 'title' }
    ];
```

and use this here:

```
    <select
       data-ng-model="option.selectedQuestionSort"
       data-ng-options="o.label for o in option.questionOrderBy">
       <option style="display: none" value="">Select Sort Order</option>
    </select>
```

and in my HTML:

```
     data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data | orderBy:option.selectedQuestion.key">
```

This works but I would like to use local storage to remember the value of the sort.

When I try to store the "option.selectedQuestionSort" this is an array !

Is there a way I could change the above so that I could store a value **in localstorage** instead of an array for option.selectedQuestionSort. Then when my code starts I 
could get the value and have the select show the right selection?

Note here's my code to store into local storage:

```
    $scope.$watch('option.selectedQuestionSort', function () {
        if ($scope.option.selectedQuestionSort != null ) {
            localStorageService.add('selectedQuestionSort', $scope.option.selectedQuestionSort);
        }
    })
```

The problem is $scope.option.selectedQuestionSort is an array so I don't think I can store that correctly.

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage -- Can't store arrays in `localStorage`, but you can use `JSON.stringify` on your array and store it, then parse it on the way out

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify(object)` when storing the data( works for objects and arrays, but might fail for items with circular reference, which isn't the case here).

When you want to get the data out, you need to convert it back to an object (or array) format, use `JSON.parse(string)` which returns the object.

So with your localStorage service is should be:

```
localStorageService.add('selectedQuestionSort', JSON.stringify($scope.option.selectedQuestionSort));
```

And when you take it out:

```
selectedOption = JSON.parse(localStorageService.get('selectedQuestionSort'));
```