# How can I save javascript variables locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in Javascript/Jquery and I am making a mobile web app using jquery mobile and jquery and I can't figure out how to display all my inputs in one place. No matter how many data I enter into the form it always displays the last entered .Please, any help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if(localStorage['linrval'],localStorage['linrdate']){
      $('#inrhist').prepend('<div class="inrval">'+localStorage['linrdate']+ '  ----  '   +localStorage['linrval']+ '</div>');
   };

$('#inrbtn').click(function(){
   var inrval=$('input[name=user]').val();
   var inrdate=$('input[name=dateinr]').val();
   localStorage.setItem('linrval',inrval);
   localStorage.setItem('linrdate',inrdate);
   $('#inrhist').prepend('<div class="inrval">'+inrdate+ '  ----  ' +inrval+ '</div>');
   });
```

Comment: you should prepare a fiddle, anyway I think you've an error in your first `if` statement `if(localStorage['linrval'],localStorage['linrdate'])` - check your js console

Comment: Is the problem when you click the button or load the page?

Comment: Where is your localstorage **getItem** ?

Comment: `if` statements don't accept commas (`,`), I think you want to use and AND statement (`&&`)

Comment: Try with array and JSON like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things need to change here every time you need to add into array instead of you update the item value with same property. `localStorage` only supports strings.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

            //localStorage.removeItem("users");

        var userStr = localStorage.getItem('users');

        if (userStr != null && userStr != undefined) {
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(userStr);

            console.log("onload value", jsonObj);

            $.each(jsonObj.items, function(i, item) {
                $('#inrhist').prepend('<div class="inrval">'+item.user +'--'+item.dateinr+'</div>');
             });
        }

        $('#inrbtn').click(function () {

            var dataItems = { items: [] };

            var inrval = $('input[name=user]').val();
            var inrdate = $('input[name=dateinr]').val();

            var item = { user: inrval, dateinr: inrdate };

            var usersList = localStorage.getItem('users');

            var jsonObj;

            if (usersList == null) {
                dataItems.items.push(item);                  
                jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataItems));
            }
            else {
                jsonObj = JSON.parse(usersList);
                jsonObj.items.push(item);
            }

            jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

            console.log(jsonStr);

            localStorage.setItem("users", jsonStr);

            $('#inrhist').prepend('<div class="inrval">' + inrdate + '--' + inrval + '</div>');

        });

    });
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p4wkY/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
if(localStorage['linrval'],localStorage['linrdate']){...}
```

Such expression is true if and only if `localStorage['linrdate']` is true. The value for `localStorage['linrval']` is basically ignored.

Perhaps you want this:

```
if( localStorage['linrval'] || localStorage['linrdate'] ){...}
                            ^^
```

You're also overwriting your localStorage values:

```
localStorage.setItem('linrval',inrval);
localStorage.setItem('linrdate',inrdate);
```