# how to add an array to localstore in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cookiestore

I am trying to build a shopping cart. I want to add the array invoice to localstorage so that i could access it later.

I guess there are some errors with this form of approach

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
function CartForm($scope, $cookieStore) {
$scope.invoice.items = $cookieStore.get('items');
$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.invoice.items.push({
        qty: 1,
        description: '',
        cost: 0
    });
   $scope.invoice.items = $cookieStore.put('items');
},

$scope.removeItem = function(index) {
    $scope.invoice.items.splice(index, 1);
 $scope.invoice.items = $cookieStore.put('items');
},

$scope.total = function() {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.invoice.items, function(item) {
        total += item.qty * item.cost;
    })

    return total;
 }
 }
```

HTML contains a button , which pushes the new items to the array which gets automatically binded.

```
<div ng:controller="CartForm">
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng:repeat="item in invoice.items">
        <td><input type="text" ng:model="item.description"class="input-small"></td>           
        <td><input type="number" ng:model="item.qty" ng:required class="input-mini">  </td>
        <td><input type="number" ng:model="item.cost" ng:required class="input-mini">  </td>
        <td>{{item.qty * item.cost | currency}}</td>
        <td>
            [<a href ng:click="removeItem($index)">X</a>]
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href ng:click="addItem()" class="btn btn-small">add item</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td>{{total() | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
localStorage["items"] = JSON.stringify(items);
```

update: you can retrieve it as follows: `var items:

```
localStorage.getItem('items');
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

Comment: thank you for your reply. how can i access it again?

Comment: `var items = localStorage.getItem('items');`

Comment: awesome! but i tried to get this done for my cart with angularjs. but it doesnt seem to be working fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/ I want the contents of the cart to be present even after refreshing.

Comment: like i tried adding    localstorage['demo'] =JSON.stringify($scope.invoice); ended up with an error.

Comment: Next time when you are posting a question,please explain your problem properly, that is another question tagged angular.js

Comment: well i am sorry. I am kinda new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Local stage saves only strings, not complex objects.

What you can do, therefore, is stringify it when saving and re-parse it when accessing it.

```
localStorage['foo'] = JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]);
```

Be aware that the stringify process will strip out any unsuitable elements in the array, e.g. functions.

To re-parse it:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage['foo']);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the response. I am trying to make this work .You can check out the JSfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/

Answer (score 0):

localStorage supports only strings, so that why you must use JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() to work via localStorage.

```
var p = [];
p[0] = "some";
localStorage["p"] = JSON.stringify(p);
```

For your code:

```
var items = [{
        qty: 10,
        description: 'item',
        cost: 9.95}];
localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
// get 
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. But i have changed the question a little bit. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` supports only strings, so you must use the following code:

```
var p = [];
p[0] = "some";
localStorage["p"] = JSON.stringify(p);
```