# localstorage - save array

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have localstorage working to where I can save inputs and push them to a list. Now I would like to save the list in localstorage because when I reload the list resets because of `var fav = new Array();` is defined at the start in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sG99W/2/). How can I work around this?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: convert it to json before saving it and decode it when retrieving it

Comment: You want to store the `fav` array in `localStorage`? Your list is not resetting on load because of the `var` declaration, it's resetting because your not saving it anywhere, and on refresh, `fav` is a new variable. To store the `fav` array in `localStorage` you would have to store it as a string. See here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's realy easy, you just need to use JSON data to save it :

```
// Save
var datas = ["1", "2", "3"];
localStorage["datas"] = JSON.stringify(datas);

// Retrieve
var stored_datas = JSON.parse(localStorage["datas"]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works; however, once I reload the page and store a new string, the array resets. New jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sG99W/3/

Comment: @Andy I managed to fix this by checking if the array was empty or not. Thanks again for the solution. http://jsfiddle.net/sG99W/5/

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on why I may be getting undefined when I console.log(stored_datas);??

Answer (score 3):

The reason some people are getting `undefined` is because of JS.. for example, if you run `[][0]` it is `undefined`. The answer from Andy/Arthur above initially worked locally for me but ended up breaking in production. I fixed it by using the methods/syntax [defined in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) using it as so...

to set a value:

```
const myArray = []
localStorage.setItem('myArray', JSON.stringify(myArray))
```

to get a value:

```
const myArrayFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('myArray')
if (myArrayFromLocalStorage && myArrayFromLocalStorage.length) {
const myArray = JSON.parse(myArrayFromLocalStorage)
}
```

to clear a value:

```
localStorage.removeItem('myArray')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do with [localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage), where you can transparently set/get any of the following "types": Array, Boolean, Date, Float, Integer, Null, Object or String.

[DISCLAIMER] I am the author of the utility [/DISCLAIMER]

Examples:

```
localDataStorage.set( 'key1', 'Belgian' );
localDataStorage.set( 'key2', 1200.0047 );
localDataStorage.set( 'key3', true );
localDataStorage.set( 'key4', { 'RSK' : [1,'3',5,'7',9] } );
localDataStorage.set( 'key5', null );

localDataStorage.get( 'key1' );   -->   'Belgian'
localDataStorage.get( 'key2' );   -->   1200.0047
localDataStorage.get( 'key3' );   -->   true
localDataStorage.get( 'key4' );   -->   Object {RSK: Array(5)}
localDataStorage.get( 'key5' );   -->   null
```

As you can see, the primitive values are respected. In your case, we would do this:

```
>localDataStorage.set( 'datas', ["1", "2", "3"] );
```

Note that we didn't need to do any stringification to our key value. You can specify it plainly and clearly. Now, when we retrieve it...

```
>localDataStorage.get( 'datas' ) -->
```

... we will get:

```
>(3) ["1", "2", "3"]
```

exactly what we started with, without having to convert anything.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent your variable from being reset try this, if you want to reload page and keep old value this is not gonna help thought.

```
  if (typeof fav === 'undefined'){
        var fav = new Array();}
```