# how to save itens name and score to localStorage in JavasScript not using JSON

Tags: javascript, save, set, local-storage

I am not understanding how to set and get more the one item per line, like name and score... I only get back the name and last score saved... 
I need doing it not using JSON :/

```
var i=0;
function saveData()
{

    var score = (Math.random()*10).toFixed();
    console.log(score);
    var player1 = "player1" + i;
    var score = "score " + i;
    i++;
    player1 = prompt("What is your player1?");
    localStorage.setItem(player1, score);
}

function showData()
{
    var show = '';
    for(var j=0 ; j<=localStorage.length-1; j++){
          key = localStorage.key(j);
          value = localStorage.getItem(key);
          show =  show+  "\n"+key;
    }
    alert(show + "\n"+ value);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to store an Array in localStorage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

Comment: I need doing it not using JSON :/

Comment: You can already fetch multiple values from the `localStorage`; are you sure you are storing more than 1 value? Have you filled in different values in the `prompt` popup?

Comment: What is the reason why you can't or don't want to use JSON?

Comment: Ok, I did it working, and now I want it sorting by score, not by name. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it working, and now I want it sorting by score, not by name. Is there a way?

```
    var sacore = (Math.random()*10).toFixed(2);
    console.log(sacore);
    var score = sacore.toString();
    var player1 = ("player1" + score+ "score") + i;
    //var score = "score " + i;
    i++;
    player1 = prompt("What is your player1?");
     player1 = player1 +" "+  (score);
    localStorage.setItem(player1, score);
```