# Storing key values array in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to store array in localstorage with following code :

```
var tempval = [];
tempval['key'] = 1;                    
localStorage.setItem("Message", JSON.stringify(tempval));
```

but in localstorage it showing only `[]`

So how to store it and where I am doing mistake ?

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways. But let me ask you of the first obvious `Where's the multidimensional array?` 
This `[ [1,2] , [3,4]]` is multidimensional array, array in array

Comment: The array you created is just like associative array and its complicated in javascript. Because js doesn't support associative array.

Comment: I understand that you want to insert `object` you try to do this `tempval.push({'key':1})`. but `multidimensional array` ?

Comment: What you do in my opinion is you set a property of the array treating  it  as object but it is still empty array. So the string representation of empty array is empty array.

Comment: This question has been answer already (duplicate of): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357615/10387837

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I store an array in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:-

```
var tempval ={};
tempval.key = 1;                    
localStorage.setItem("Message", JSON.stringify(tempval));
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, now here Key is dynamic value like key = "test@123" , so it possible to take dynamic key there ?

Comment: @Er.KT please explain exactly what you want to do!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes.Arrays always use numbered indexes in javascript. Use object if you wanna use named index.

**Using array** (numbered index)

```
var tempval = [];
tempval[0] = 1;
```

**Using object** (named index)

```
 var tempval = {};
 tempval['key'] = 1;
```

Use `var tempval ={};` instead of `var tempval = [];`

Answer (score 0):

So Your Question is not that much clear to me but i am trying to give you a general solution for storing multidimensional array in local storage ,

```
    var a= [[1,2,3],["hello","world"]]; // multi dimentional array 
    console.log(a);
    var b = JSON.stringify(a); // converting the array into a string 
    console.log(b);
    localStorage.setItem("TestData",b); // storing the string in localstorage
    var c= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("TestData")); //accessing the data from localstorgae.
    console.log(c);
```

[Here is the code running in Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/lozerazobu/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answer already (duplicate of):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357615/10387837

The short answer is `localStorage.setItem` only supports strings as arguments. In order to use it with arrays its recommended to use `JSON.stringify()` to pass the parameter and `JSON.parse()` to get the array.

Comment: Then, maybe, flagging this question as a duplicate is needed.

Comment: @AntonMenshov I did flag the question , I'm waiting for the flag to be moderated.