# Uncaught TypeError: titles.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to push

```
titles.push(title);
```

but there's an error when I try to run it: titles.push is not a function.

Full code:

```
    var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
        localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.innerHTML); 
    var titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");
        if(titles == null) 
            titles = new Array();
        if(titles.indexOf(title) < 0) 
            titles.push(title); 
        localStorage.setItem("titles", titles); 
    }
```

Comment: could you also mention what `title` is in your code? By the looks of it, title is not defined. Other than that, the code looks fine.

Comment: localStorage do not support storing arrays. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage

Comment: To use the push function of an Array your variable needs to be an Array. Looks like in your case the type of your variable isn't what you think it is.

Comment: I declared titles = new Array(); though, doesn't that make my variable an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local Storage can only store strings, not arrays:

> [*localStorage*.setItem(*keyName*, *keyValue*);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)
>
> **keyName**
>   A [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) containing the name of the key you want to create/update.
>
> **keyValue**
>   A [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) containing the value you want to give the key you are creating/updating.

This means you will need to save a serialized string representation of your array to `localStorage` and, likewise, deserialize an array when you retrieve. Luckily, JavaScript has some built in utils to do this for you by using `[JSON.parse][3]` and `[JSON.stringify][3]`.

Something like this:

```
var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
var titles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('titles') || '[]');
if(titles.indexOf(title) < 0) {
  titles.push(title);
}
localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
```