# Javascript localstorage get the value into array one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays, storage, frontend, local

Problem:
I would like get the localstorage value "car", i want to get the result like   car = ["red","blue"] in other page, i want to get the result into array one by one. How can i fix it?

```
page 1:
car = ["red","blue"];
localStorage.setItem("car", JSON.stringify(car));

 Another Page:
  var car1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("car"));  
  alert(car1[0])  
   ****show two record at the same time , i want to put it into array like car1[0] = red; car1[1] = blue;
```

Comment: Do you even know what the JSON.stringify call on your first page does? if you did, you wouldn't need to ask this.

Comment: It's very unclear what the problem is. The other element is in `car1[1]`.

Comment: You need to put more effort into explaining the situation and specific problem. Take some time to read [ask]

Answer (score -3):

as i know, when you convert it to json it wouldn't parse to you items like array 
so `car[0]` doesn't work as you want,
This is a good resource of using localstorage:
 https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

U must enter the items as an object and give them an id
like this:

```
{
 name: red,
 id: 1,
}
```

Then retrieve it by car id.

and a better answer: [How do I store an array in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

And know it JSON is not supported in IE7 and earlier.