# how to store in phonegap from ajax to localStorage

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, cordova, local-storage

We have an App works with cordova [phonegap] 
we wish to perform offline saving of a results into cache memory

results comes from the server [PHP]
than using ajax & javascript results shown in the webview

I try to use localStorage for keeping last used values [2] when user is in offline mode [no wifi/3G]. USD/EURO or USD/ILS i.e.

using jQuery
normally works

```
        $('.loading').fadeOut();

        var $response           = $(result);
        var result              = $response.filter('#result').html();
        var result_1            = $response.filter('#result_1').html();
        var result_10           = $response.filter('#result_10').html();
        var result_100          = $response.filter('#result_100').html();
        var result_1000         = $response.filter('#result_1000').html();

        $('.convertfrom_txt').each(function() { $(this).text(cfrom_str); })
        $('.convertto_txt').each(function() { $(this).text(cto_str); })

        $('#cresult').text(result + ' ' + cto_str);
        $('#one_unit').text(result_1);
        $('#ten_unit').text(result_10);
        $('#hundred_unit').text(result_100);
        $('#thousand_unit').text(result_1000);
```

Offline assuming value changes everyday. [currencies]

```
var currency = [10]; //10 currencies max to save offline

var currency = result_1 ; //save result of 1 coin to array

var offline;
//Check connection
function onDeviceReady() {
    var offlineData = window.localStorage.getItem("result_1");

    if (window.navigator.onLine) offline = false;
}

if (offline == false) 
    {
        document.getElementById('result_1').value = "currency[0]";
        document.getElementById('result_10').value = "currency[0]*10";
        document.getElementById('result_100').value = "currency[0]*100";
        document.getElementById('result_1000').value = "currency[0]*1000";
        document.getElementById('time').value = "time";
    }
```

result_1 represents the value of one conversion.
we wish to store values of 1 USD and 1 Euro in an array, offline

I 'm not sure which better way to choose

localStorage taken form official 
[Docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html)

```
var storage = localStorage;

var value = storage.getItem(key); // Pass a key name to get its value.

storage.setItem(key, value) // Pass a key name and its value to add or update that key.

storage.removeItem(key) // Pass a key name to remove that key from storage.
```

2. Will such local storage works under common Android devices?

Thanks

Comment: See more info [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html)

Comment: What is your question? How to [store array in local storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage) or what?

Comment: Yes Pavlo you've actually put a link I put in the question

Comment: See attached querstion link how to implement it

Answer (score 1):

`LocalStorage` is supported by all Cordova platforms including `Android`. Info from [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html).

How to store array in LocalStorage is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

Comment: I'm using numbers (3.5556) do I need an array for that or should I use it as string.thanks for reference

Comment: As I know you can use JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(yourStorageKey)) to correct parse number from `LocalStorage`