# How to save array and object at once in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

```
var mara =  [{"name":"zach", "age":"27"}];    
var marathon2 = [{"ticketDetails" : [mara]}];
localStorage.setItem("ticket_marathon2",JSON.stringify($scope.ticket_marathon2));    
var details2 = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("ticket_marathon2") );    
console.log("data2",details2);
```

Comment: What doesn't work if any ? Does it throw an error in your console ?

Comment: So what the issue? looks like you object math to your model

Comment: @sabik  when i run this the array on  "ticketDetails":[mara] is right but when i save n localstorage the data gone

Comment: So please add it as an [edit] to your question, how can we guess such information ? And also, include what kind of object is `mara`.

Comment: @Kaiido array in mara is a simple array such as " name : zach "

Comment: Well in this last snippet, you are stringifying `$scope.ticket_marathon2` while you have built `var marathon2`with `mara`. Didn't you mean `JSON.stringify(marathon2)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `var mara = [{"name":"zach", "age":"27"}];` - defined as an array with one object.

Afterwards: `var marathon2 = [{"ticketDetails" : [mara]}];`

stating that "ticketDetails" is an array with an array inside resulting in:

[{"ticketDetails": [[{"name":"zach"....}]]}] ?

Maybe remove [], unless it's intentional.

Another thing, try stringifying mara array as well, before adding it as the value of the object and stringifying it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mara = [{"name":"zach", "age":"27"}];
var marathon2 = [{"ticketDetails" : mara}];

localStorage.setItem("ticket_marathon2",JSON.stringify(marathon2));

var details2 = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("ticket_marathon2") );

alert(JSON.stringify(details2[0].ticketDetails[0].name));
```

Comment: have you injected `$localStorage` to controller?

Comment: the array appear on the first console but it gone when the second console so i can assume tht it did not save properly into localstorage

Comment: the problem is "ticketDetails": [mara], since all the other is an object only this part that an array

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem("ticket_marathon1", angular.toJson($scope.ticket_marathon1));

var details1 = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem("ticket_marathon1"));
```

Note: You dont need to inject $localStorage its a default html5 storage.

Comment: without injecting `$localStorage` to controller, its not possible.

Comment: @zach this is out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage

Comment: Do not assign var value in $scope simply store in localstorage directly have a look. https://jsfiddle.net/akgx7Lqu/84/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 $window.localStorage.setItem("ticket_marathon1",angular.toJson($scope.ticket_marathon1))
```

to store,
`var details1 =angular.fromJson($window.localStorage.getItem("ticket_marathon1"))` to retrieve and `$window.localStorage.removeItem("ticket_marathon1")` to remove.Then you can access the values in any page and it is more flexible.

**Note**:Inject $window in your controller

Comment: sorry @Vivz it didn't work i'm still missing my array in  "ticketDetails": [mara],

Comment: Can you try to store it explicitly like $window.localStorage.setItem("mara",angular.toJson($scope.ticket_marathon1.ticketDetails)) and see if it is working

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position "i got this error"

Comment: I think localstorage only store strings. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage for more details. I hope this helps.