# Saving and getting an array in Localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to save an array into localstorage and then get it.

```
localStorage.setItem("savedquestionslist", questions);
console.log(localStorage.getItem(savedquestionslist));
```

The variable 'questions' is an array.

However I get this error:

> ReferenceError: savedquestionslist is not defined.

I still get the error even if I do this:

```
localStorage.setItem("savedquestionslist", "test");
console.log(localStorage.getItem(savedquestionslist));
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I store an array in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

`savedquestionslist` needs to be a string.

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('savedquestionslist'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your syntax for `getItem`.

It takes in a string as an argument. You are passing a variable and the error represents that the variable `savedquestionslist` is not defined.

Change your code to :

```
localStorage.setItem("savedquestionslist", questions);
console.log(localStorage.getItem("savedquestionslist"));
```

An example would be

```js
var questions = ['firstQuestion', 'secondQuestion', 'thirdQuestion'];

localStorage.setItem("savedquestionslist", questions);
console.log(localStorage.getItem("savedquestionslist"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you forgot the quotes in the `getItem` call:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem("savedquestionslist"));
// ------------------------------^------------------^
```

Or you can use literal access:

```
console.log(localStorage.savedquestionslist);
```

But in both cases, since local storage only stores **strings**, I'd use JSON, since otherwise your array won't be saved / retrieved correctly:

```
localStorage.setItem("savedquestionslist", JSON.stringify(questions));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedquestionslist")) || []);
```

(The `|| []` is for if you've never set the item, it provides a default of an empty array.)