# Problem Pulling Specific Values From A LocalStorage List in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pull specific values from a list in localStorage. Here's an example:

```
Key: Boise, ID, Value: ["43.616","-116.202","Boise, ID"]
```

I need to split the three values out, but the problem is, I can't use

```
var storedLocationsArray = value.split(',');
```

because I need "Boise, ID" to remain as an intact string. "ID" is not a 4th value. Another issue I'm having is if I just console.log():

```
latitude = storedLocationsArray[0];
```

I get this: **Lat: ["43.616"**. I can use .replace() functions to get rid of the quotes and brackets, but I still have the problem of the third value being split into two values if there is a comma.

Comment: Isn't `Value` an array? I might be missing something here, but why do you need to `.split` or `.replace`? Can't you just access the array, like `value[0]`?

Comment: I tried that and got just the first bracket: "Lat: [" I think there's something different about a localStorage array.

Comment: Where does `Lat:[` come from? I don't see it in your example

Comment: lat = value[0];  console.log("Lat: " + lat);

Comment: Also having trouble understanding your question or what the required outcome is; the elements under the `Value` key in localStorage are in an array, and therefore already discrete, separate entities.

Comment: You saving this data into the local storage, or you have it as given?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

I was right localStorage only supports strings. Found the answer here and it works: [How do I store an array in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

```
key = localStorage.key(i);

var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
lat = value[0];
```