# Using localStorage/sessionStorage to store arrays

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to save an array inside of a localStorage value. I can only access chars of the value, not the grouped value. I have been trying to write a function to group them by commas, but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

```
// setting values
localStorage.setItem("foo", [15,"bye"]);

// writes the whole thing.
document.write(localStorage.getItem("foo")); // returns 15,bye

// only writes the first character, instead of one part of the array 
// (in this case it would be 15).
document.write(localStorage.getItem("foo")[0]); // returns 1
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to set the data and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to fetch the stored data.

Try this:

```
localStorage.setItem("foo", JSON.stringify([15,"bye"]));

// writes the whole thing.
localStorage.getItem("foo"); // returns 15,bye

var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("foo"));
console.log(data[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` can only store string in its value, that is why it is storing only 15;

Use `JSON.stringify` and store it in the local storage as `localStorage.setItem("foo",JSON.stringify([15,"bye"]))`;

If you want to retrieve the value do as `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("foo"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json

```
let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("foo"));
console.log(data[0])
```

Or you can split by ',' and get the `0th` index item.

```
localStorage.getItem('foo').split(',')[0]
```