# Store values in javascript session and access it when required

Tags: javascript, session

I am working on a project where there is no user login system where people come and select multiple events they want to be in. From javascript, I wrote a code where if a user clicks it will store the id of an event in a javascript array but when I go to the checkout page the data gets cleared. So I came up with the idea of using localstorage of javascript. I have reached here:

```
var myData = '';
var livalue = [];
$('.party_a').on('click', function(e){
    alert('One item added to the cart!');
    sessionStorage.setItem("livalue", $(this).val());
    alert(localStorage.getItem("livalue"));
    myData = partyName.length;
    if(myData == 1){
      $('#cart').html("<li><a href='{{ route('checkout') }}'>My Cart<sup id='cart_number'></sup></a></li>");
    }
    $('#cart_number').html(myData);
});
```

But when I try to alert the `livalue`, it gives me null. Any suggestion on this matter is appreciated.

Comment: What is `.party_a` element? An `li`? Notice also, that `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document.

Comment: `$(this).val()` represetn btn, u need to get input or data here.. `$(this).val()` will be null/undefined for button

Comment: or use `$(this).attr("id")` something. similar

Comment: if you are setting data in session storage then how could you get item from localstorage
```localStorage.setItem("livalue", $(this).val());   alert(localStorage.getItem("livalue")); ```

Comment: @xdeepakv I am getting value using `$(this).val()` and now I want to store it in a session.

Comment: Try: `alert(sessionStorage.getItem("livalue"))`

Comment: @Teemu `party_a` is a class that I have used in every 'a' tag I have used. `Id`s should be unique that is why I used class.

Comment: @palaѕн It gives me null

Comment: @xdeepakv I am getting value on click event now I want to store it in a session and use it in a checkout page.

Comment: It seems to work fine to me: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/da63wfe7/). You can refresh the page multiple times to see the session value.

Comment: `a` tags don't have `value`, maybe you need `href` instead. `<sup id='cart_number'>` contains a hardcoded id. Notice also what others have said about `sessionStorage/localStorage`.

Comment: @palaѕн I have reloaded it multiple times but also it is not showing data.

Comment: Its showing data for me. What OS, machine, browser are you testing this on?

Comment: @palaѕн I am checking this on chrome and windows.

Comment: @palaѕн Yes, it is working now!. But as I am using it to collect selected product it. I want to store array. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage