# Use local-storage to store array as a value and update it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to use save some data in localstorage. Here I am trying ,

```
let marks = localstorage.getItem('marks') || []
```

Here Now, I am trying to add elements into this array using some action.

```
const addMarks = () => {
  
localstorage.setItem('marks', ['10'])   

}
```

Then I am using this variable to render the marks like

```
marks.map((index, mark) => {

  return <h1>mark</h1>

})
```

But this way it does not work as `localstorage`  only supports the string as a `value`.

How do I implement this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I store an array in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

Serialize it [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
and parse it back [Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` only support strings as values, you'll have to `JSON.stringify` your objects when saving them and `JSON.parse` them when retrieving them

```
let marks = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('marks')) || [];

const addMarks = () => {
  localstorage.setItem('marks', JSON.stringify(['10']))   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just use the .split() method? If you make an array ['10', '9', '8'], you will get '10,9,8'. Just use .split(',') and you will get an array!

localStorage.getItem('marks').split(',')