# Calculating values from inputs in jQuery and Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, jquery, spring, thymeleaf

When I add the selected book to the session, it will appear here. Whatever I do with JQuery, for example to multiply the number and the price, it just takes the values from the first row for one book that appeared, it doesn't recognize the others ?!

```
<form id="form">
    <div th:unless="${session.choosenBooksForUser.empty}" id="dataTable" >
        <ul>
            <li name="line_items" th:each="itBook: ${session.choosenBooksForUser}">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span>Name of book:<a th:href="|books/Details?id=${itBook.id}|" th:text="${itBook.name}" name="name"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <span>Author:<span th:text="${itBook.author}" name="itBook.author"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <span>Number of Book to Buy:<input class="numberOfBooksToBuy" type="number" value="1" min="1" id="numberOfBooksToBuy"  onkeyup="if(this.value<0){this.value= this.value * -1}" name="numberOfBooksToBuy"/></span>
                <span>Price: <input type="number"  th:value="${itBook.price}" name="price" id="price"  class="price" onkeyup="if(this.value<0){this.value= this.value * -1}" readonly/></span>
                <br>
                <br>
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</from>
```

Need to change the tag named NumberOfBooksToBuy

```
<span>Number of Book to Buy:<input oninput='saveValue(this);'  class="numberOfBooksToBuy" type="number" value="1" min="1" id="numberOfBooksToBuy"  onkeyup="if(this.value<0){this.value= this.value * -1}" name="numberOfBooksToBuy"/></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    

 document.getElementById("numberOfBooksToBuy").value = getSavedValue("numberOfBooksToBuy");    

 function saveValue(e){
    var id = e.id; 
    var val = e.value; 
    localStorage.setItem(id, val);
}


function getSavedValue  (v){
    if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
        return "";
    }
    return localStorage.getItem(v);
}  

    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, show your jquery code which you have tried.

Comment: I worked in a lot of ways, so I deleted a lot of them. I tried using the jAutoCalc plugin and it didn't work. Here I will show the code to store the value in the NumberOfBooksToBuy input when the page is reloaded, for all books that are displayed, but still only works for the first book or the first line that is displayed.

Comment: Hi so you need to store the total value inside localStorage ? Did you try saving values like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage) ?