# Can anyone please help me to add a Scoreboard in canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I need some help with a project I'm working on. I am busy trying to code my first canvas game ever.
I'm pretty happy with the result so far but I can't for the life of me add a High score system into the game. I tried a few things and have determined that it would probably be easiest to use localStorage to save the scores but I'm a complete noob. If anyone could point me in the right direction That would be great.

This is my first time posting anything here so sorry if I left out something important.

You can see what I have done so far here: `https://jsfiddle.net/Heino/hkwog58j/2/`

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Load the background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
var paused = false;
var collisionL = false;
var collisionR = false;
var collisionT = false;
var collisionB = false;
var again = false;
var available = false;
var double = false;
var spawn = false;
var coins = 0;
var finalScore = 0;

var wallImage = new Image();
wallImage.src = "https://heinostobbia.github.io/CATCHem/wall.jpg";


bgImage.onload = function() {
  // show the background image
  bgReady = true;
};

bgImage.src = "https://heinostobbia.github.io/CATCHem/background.png";

// Load the hero image
var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();

heroImage.onload = function() {
  // show the hero image
  heroReady = true;
};

if (coins <= 10) {

  heroImage.src = "https://heinostobbia.github.io/CATCHem/hero.png";
}

// Load the monster image
var monsterReady = false;
var monsterImage = new Image();

var monster1Ready = false;
var monster1Image = new Image();

var monster2Ready = false;
var monster2Image = new Image();

monsterImage.onload = function() {
  // show the monster image
  monsterReady = true;
};

monster1Image.onload = function() {
  // show the monster1 image
  monster1Ready = true;
};

monster2Image.onload = function() {
  // show the monster2 image
  monster2Ready = true;
};

monsterImage.src = "https://heinostobbia.github.io/CATCHem/monster.png";
monster1Image.src = "https://heinostobbia.github.io/CATCHem/monster.png";
monster2Image.src = "https://heinostobbia.github.io/CATCHem/monster1.png";

// Load the coin image 
var coinReady = false;
var coinImage = new Image();

coinImage.onload = function() {
  // show the coin image
  coinReady = true;
};

coinImage.src = "https://heinostobbia.github.io/CATCHem/coin.png";

// Create the game objects
var hero = {
  speed: 256, // movement speed of hero in pixels per second
};


var monster = {};
var monster1 = {};
var monster2 = {};
var monstersCaught = 0;

var walls = {};

var coin = {};

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};
var keysPress = {};

// Check for keys pressed where key represents the keycode captured
addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function(key) {
    keysDown[key.keyCode] = true;
  },
  false
);

addEventListener(
  "keyup",
  function(key) {
    delete keysDown[key.keyCode];
  },
  false
);

addEventListener(
  "keypress",
  function(key) {
    // pauses game when spacebar is pressed
    if (key.keyCode == 32) {

      if (paused) {
        paused = false;
      } else {
        paused = true;
      }
    }

    // starts new game when spacebar is pressed when game is finished
    if (key.keyCode == 32 && finished) {
      location.reload();
    }
  },
  false
);

// Place the player in center of canvas
hero.x = canvas.width / 2;
hero.y = canvas.height / 2;

// Reset the monster and coin positions when player catches a monster
var reset = function() {

  // Place the monster somewhere on the canvas randomly
  monster.x = 32 + Math.random() * (canvas.width - 72);
  monster.y = 32 + Math.random() * (canvas.height - 72);

  if (monstersCaught >= 5) {
    // Place the monster somewhere on the canvas randomly
    monster1.x = 32 + Math.random() * (canvas.width - 72);
    monster1.y = 32 + Math.random() * (canvas.height - 72);

  }

  fifth = monstersCaught % 10;

  if (fifth == 9) {
    // Place the monster somewhere on the canvas randomly
    monster2.x = 32 + Math.random() * (canvas.width - 72);
    monster2.y = 32 + Math.random() * (canvas.height - 72);

  } else {
    monster2.x = 600;
    monster2.y = 600;
  }

  // Outer Walls
  walls.x = canvas.width - 8;
  walls.y = canvas.height - 8;

  // Place the coin somewhere on the canvas randomly
  if (coinReady) {
    coin.x = 32 + Math.random() * (canvas.width - 72);
    coin.y = 32 + Math.random() * (canvas.height - 72);
  }

};

// Update game objects - change player position based on key pressed
var update = function(modifier) {
  if (!paused && !finished) {

    // arrow keys
    if (38 in keysDown && !collisionT) {
      // Player is holding UP arrow
      hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if (40 in keysDown && !collisionB) {
      // Player is holding DOWN arrow
      hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if (37 in keysDown && !collisionL) {
      // Player is holding LEFT arrow
      hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if (39 in keysDown && !collisionR) {
      // Player is holding RIGHT arrow
      hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    // W A S D keys
    if (87 in keysDown && !collisionT) {
      // Player is holding W key
      hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if (83 in keysDown && !collisionB) {
      // Player is holding S key
      hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if (65 in keysDown && !collisionL) {
      // Player is holding A key
      hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    if (68 in keysDown && !collisionR) {
      // Player is holding D key
      hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
    }
  }

  // Check if player and monster collide
  if (hero.x <= monster.x + 32 && monster.x <= hero.x + 32 && hero.y <= monster.y + 32 && monster.y <= hero.y + 32) {

    if (double) {
      monstersCaught = monstersCaught + 2;
    } else {

      ++monstersCaught;
    }
    available = false;
    reset();
  }

  // places coin when monstersCaught in even number
  var remainder = monstersCaught % 2;

  if (remainder == 1) {
    coinReady = true;

  } else {
    coinReady = false;
  }

  // Check if player and monster1 collide
  if (hero.x <= monster1.x + 32 && monster1.x <= hero.x + 32 && hero.y <= monster1.y + 32 && monster1.y <= hero.y + 32) {
    if (double) {
      monstersCaught = monstersCaught + 2;
    } else {

      ++monstersCaught;
    }
    available = false;
    reset();
  }

  // Check if player and monster2 collide
  if (hero.x <= monster2.x + 32 && monster2.x <= hero.x + 32 && hero.y <= monster2.y + 32 && monster2.y <= hero.y + 32 && !available) {
    monster2.x = 32 + Math.random() * (canvas.width - 72);
    monster2.y = 32 + Math.random() * (canvas.height - 72);
    available = true;

  }

  if (hero.x <= monster2.x + 32 && monster2.x <= hero.x + 32 && hero.y <= monster2.y + 32 && monster2.y <= hero.y + 32 && available) {
    if (double) {
      monstersCaught = monstersCaught + 6;
    } else {

      monstersCaught = monstersCaught + 3;
    }
    available = false;
    reset();

  }

  // Check if player and coin collide
  if (coinReady) {

    if (hero.x <= coin.x + 25 && coin.x <= hero.x + 25 && hero.y <= coin.y + 25 && coin.y <= hero.y + 25) {

      ++coins;

      if (coins >= 5 && coins <= 6) {

        heroImage.src = "https://heinostobbia.github.io/CATCHem/hero2.png";
        double = true;

      } else {

        double = false;
      }

      if (coins >= 6 && !double) {

        heroImage.src = "https://heinostobbia.github.io/CATCHem/hero.png";
        double = false;
      }

      reset();
    }
  }


  // Check if player and RIGHT Wall collide
  if (hero.x > walls.x - 37) {
    collisionR = true;

  } else {
    collisionR = false;
  }

  // Check if player and LEFT Wall collide
  if (hero.x < (walls.x - 487)) {
    collisionL = true;

  } else {
    collisionL = false;
  }

  // Check if player and TOP Wall collide
  if (hero.y < (walls.y - 452)) {
    collisionT = true;

  } else {
    collisionT = false;
  }

  // Check if player and BOTTOM Wall collide
  if (hero.y > walls.y - 43) {
    collisionB = true;

  } else {
    collisionB = false;
  }

  // Check if player and HORIZONTAL TOP maze collide
  if (hero.y < walls.y - 333 && hero.y > walls.y - 385 && hero.x < walls.x - 124 && hero.x > walls.x - 126) {
    collisionL = true;
  }

  if (hero.x < walls.x - 124) {

    if (hero.y > walls.y - 385 && hero.y < walls.y - 380) {
      collisionB = true;
    }

    if (hero.y > walls.y - 333 && hero.y < walls.y - 328) {
      collisionT = true;
    }
  }

  // Check if player and HORIZONTAL BOTTOM maze collide
  if (hero.y > walls.y - 195 && hero.y < walls.y - 139 && hero.x > walls.x - 185 && hero.x < walls.x - 180) {
    collisionR = true;
  }

  if (hero.x > walls.x - 185) {
    if (hero.y > walls.y - 195 && hero.y < walls.y - 190) {
      collisionB = true;
    }

    if (hero.y > walls.y - 140 && hero.y < walls.y - 135) {
      collisionT = true;
    }
  }

  // Check if player and VERTICAL MIDDLE maze collide
  if (hero.x > walls.x - 290 && hero.x < walls.x - 243 && hero.y < walls.y - 333 && hero.y > walls.y - 447) {
    collisionB = true;
  }

  if (hero.y < walls.y - 380 && hero.y > walls.y - 447) {

    if (hero.x > walls.x - 297 && hero.x < walls.x - 292) {
      collisionR = true;
    }

    if (hero.x > walls.x - 245 && hero.x < walls.x - 240) {
      collisionL = true;
    }
  }

  // Check if player and VERTICAL RIGHT maze collide
  if (hero.x > walls.x - 184 && hero.x < walls.x - 132 && hero.y < walls.y - 70 && hero.y > walls.y - 75) {
    collisionT = true;
  }

  if (hero.y > walls.y - 190 && hero.y < walls.y - 77) {

    if (hero.x > walls.x - 187 && hero.x < walls.x - 182) {
      collisionR = true;
    }

    if (hero.x < walls.x - 132 && hero.x > walls.x - 137) {
      collisionL = true;
    }
  }

  // Check if player and VERTICAL LEFT maze collide
  if (hero.x > walls.x - 390 && hero.x < walls.x - 344 && hero.y > walls.y - 305 && hero.y < walls.y - 300) {
    collisionB = true;
  }

  if (hero.y > walls.y - 305) {

    if (hero.x > walls.x - 390 && hero.x < walls.x - 385) {
      collisionR = true;
    }

    if (hero.x < walls.x - 344 && hero.x > walls.x - 349) {
      collisionL = true;
    }
  }

  // Check if monster and Horizontal Top maze Wall collide
  if (monster.y < walls.y - 333 && monster.y > walls.y - 385 && monster.x < walls.x - 124) {
    monster.y = monster.y - 12;
  }

  // Check if monster and Horizontal Bottom maze Wall collide
  if (monster.y > walls.y - 190 && monster.y < walls.y - 140 && monster.x > walls.x - 185) {
    monster.y = monster.y + 12;
  }

  // Check if monster and vertical Middle maze Wall collide
  if (monster.x > walls.x - 297 && monster.x < walls.x - 245 && monster.y < walls.y - 333 && monster.y > walls.y - 447) {
    monster.y = monster.y + 20;
    monster.x = monster.x - 20;
  }

  // Check if monster and vertical right maze Wall collide
  if (monster.x > walls.x - 184 && monster.x < walls.x - 132 && monster.y < walls.y - 70 && monster.y > walls.y - 195) {
    monster.x = monster.x + 12;
  }

  // Check if monster and vertical left maze Wall collide
  if (monster.x > walls.x - 390 && monster.x < walls.x - 344 && monster.y > walls.y - 305) {
    monster.x = monster.x - 12;
  }

  // Check if monster1 and Horizontal Top maze Wall collide
  if (monster1.y < walls.y - 333 && monster1.y > walls.y - 385 && monster1.x < walls.x - 124) {
    monster1.y = monster.y + 12;
  }

  // Check if monster1 and Horizontal Bottom maze Wall collide
  if (monster1.y > walls.y - 190 && monster1.y < walls.y - 140 && monster1.x > walls.x - 185) {
    monster1.y = monster1.y + 12;
  }

  // Check if monster1 and vertical Middle maze Wall collide
  if (monster1.x > walls.x - 297 && monster1.x < walls.x - 245 && monster1.y < walls.y - 333 && monster1.y > walls.y - 447) {
    monster1.x = monster1.x - 20;
    monster1.y = monster1.y - 20;
  }

  // Check if monster1 and vertical right maze Wall collide
  if (monster1.x > walls.x - 184 && monster1.x < walls.x - 132 && monster1.y < walls.y - 70 && monster1.y > walls.y - 195) {
    monster1.x = monster1.x + 12;
  }

  // Check if monster1 and vertical left maze Wall collide
  if (monster1.x > walls.x - 390 && monster1.x < walls.x - 344 && monster1.y > walls.y - 305) {
    monster1.x = monster1.x - 12;
  }

  // Check if monster2 and Horizontal Top maze Wall collide
  if (monster2.y < walls.y - 333 && monster2.y > walls.y - 385 && monster2.x < walls.x - 124) {
    monster2.y = monster.y + 12;
  }

  // Check if monster2 and Horizontal Bottom maze Wall collide
  if (monster2.y > walls.y - 190 && monster2.y < walls.y - 140 && monster2.x > walls.x - 185) {
    monster2.y = monster2.y + 12;
  }

  // Check if monster2 and vertical Middle maze Wall collide
  if (monster2.x > walls.x - 297 && monster2.x < walls.x - 245 && monster2.y < walls.y - 333 && monster2.y > walls.y - 447) {
    monster2.x = monster2.x - 20;
    monster2.y = monster2.y - 20;
  }

  // Check if monster2 and vertical right maze Wall collide
  if (monster2.x > walls.x - 184 && monster2.x < walls.x - 132 && monster2.y < walls.y - 70 && monster2.y > walls.y - 195) {
    monster2.x = monster2.x + 12;
  }

  // Check if monster2 and vertical left maze Wall collide
  if (monster2.x > walls.x - 390 && monster2.x < walls.x - 344 && monster2.y > walls.y - 305) {
    monster2.x = monster2.x - 12;
  }

  // Check if coin and Horizontal Top maze Wall collide
  if (coin.y < walls.y - 333 && coin.y > walls.y - 385 && coin.x < walls.x - 124) {
    coin.y = coin.y - 15;
  }

  // Check if coin and Horizontal Bottom maze Wall collide
  if (coin.y > walls.y - 190 && coin.y < walls.y - 140 && coin.x > walls.x - 185) {
    coin.y = coin.y + 15;
  }

  // Check if coin and vertical Middle maze Wall collide
  if (coin.x > walls.x - 297 && coin.x < walls.x - 245 && coin.y < walls.y - 333 && coin.y > walls.y - 447) {
    coin.x = coin.x - 15;
  }

  // Check if coin and vertical right maze Wall collide
  if (coin.x > walls.x - 184 && coin.x < walls.x - 132 && coin.y < walls.y - 70 && coin.y > walls.y - 195) {
    coin.x = coin.x + 15;
  }

  // Check if coin and vertical left maze Wall collide
  if (coin.x > walls.x - 390 && coin.x < walls.x - 344 && coin.y > walls.y - 305) {
    coin.x = coin.x - 15;
  }
};

// Draws everything on canvas
function render() {
  if (bgReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
  }

  if (heroReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
  }

  if (monsterReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
  }

  if (monster1Ready) {
    ctx.drawImage(monster1Image, monster1.x, monster1.y);
  }

  if (monster2Ready) {
    ctx.drawImage(monster2Image, monster2.x, monster2.y);
  }

  if (coinReady && !finished) {
    ctx.drawImage(coinImage, coin.x, coin.y);
  }

  // OUTER Walls
  texture = ctx.createPattern(wallImage, "repeat");
  ctx.strokeStyle = texture;
  ctx.strokeRect(5.5, 9, 501, 463);
  ctx.lineWidth = 18;

  // MAZE Walls
  ctx.beginPath();

  //MAZE wall horizontal top
  ctx.moveTo(8, 130);
  ctx.lineTo(380, 130);
  ctx.stroke();

  // MAZE Wall horizontal bottom
  ctx.moveTo(500, 320);
  ctx.lineTo(350, 320);
  ctx.stroke();

  // MAZE wall vertical middle
  ctx.moveTo(250, 130);
  ctx.lineTo(250, 60);
  ctx.stroke();

  // MAZE wall Vertical Right
  ctx.moveTo(150, 200);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 500);
  ctx.stroke();

  // MAZE wall Vertical left
  ctx.moveTo(359, 320);
  ctx.lineTo(359, 400);
  ctx.stroke();

  // Display score and time
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
  ctx.font = "20px Helvetica";
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + monstersCaught, 20, 20);
  ctx.fillText("Time: " + count, 20, 45);
  ctx.textAlign = "right";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillText("Coins: " + coins, 495, 20);

  // Display game over message when timer finished
  if (finished) {
    ctx.fillText("Game over!", 300, 220);
    ctx.fillText("Press SPACE to play again", 365, 250);
  }

  // display paused message when paused
  if (paused == true && finished == false) {
    ctx.fillText("Paused", 300, 220);
  }
};

var count = 30; // Game Length in seconds (Default = 30)
var finished = false;

var counter = function() {
  // stops timer while hame is paused
  if (paused) {
    count = count;

  } else {
    count = count - 1;
  }

  // when count reaches 0 clear the timer, hide the monster and hero and finish the game
  if (count <= 0) {

    // stop the timer
    clearInterval(counter);

    // set game to finished
    finished = true;
    count = 0;
    finalScore = monstersCaught;

    // hide monster, hero and coin
    monsterReady = false;
    monster1Ready = false;
    monster2Ready = false;
    heroReady = false;
    coinReady = false;
  }
};

// timer interval is every second (1000ms)
setInterval(counter, 1000);

// THE MAIN GAME LOOP
var main = function() {

  // run the update function
  update(0.02); // DO NOT CHANGE!!! (character speed default = 0.02)

  // run the render function
  render();

  // Request to do this again ASAP
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

// Let's play this game!
reset();
main();
```

Comment: i tried using: var Score = localStorage.getItem("Score"); to set the score and then when the timer runs out: document.getElementById("1st").innerHTML = "1: <strong style='font-size: 15px;'>Name" + Score + "</strong>"; but the problem is each time a new game starts the board gets wiped again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array for your scores, and then save them
"`localStorage.setItem("HighScores", JSON.stringify(scores))`"

[How do I store an array in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage)

And finally you use a for loop to get and set all scores on your leaderboard
Remember that to get your scores you use "`localStorage.getItem()`"